# Using vuetify card like bootstrap cards columns

Tags: vuejs2, bootstrap-4, vue-component, vuetify.js

I need a way to use list of `v-card` from Vuetify like [Bootstrap Card Columns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/card/#card-columns)

**Possible solution**:

Pardon me, I couldn't plunkr the code :(

This is what I did.

Update: Unfortunately this messes up with the v-ripple directive

```
<template>
<v-container grid-list-md>
    <div class="v-card-columns">
        <v-card tile v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
            <v-card-title primary-title>
                <h3 headline>
                    {{post.title}}
                </h3>
            </v-card-title>
            <v-card-text>
                {{post.body}}
            </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
    </div>
</v-container>
</template>
<script>

import axios from "axios";

export default {
    name: "All",
    data() {
        return {
            posts: []
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        axios
            .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
            .then(res => {
                this.posts = res.data
            })
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.v-card-columns .v-card {
    margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
    .v-card-columns {
        -webkit-column-count: 3;
        -moz-column-count: 3;
        column-count: 3;
        -webkit-column-gap: 1.25rem;
        -moz-column-gap: 1.25rem;
        column-gap: 1.25rem;
        orphans: 1;
        widows: 1;
    }

    .v-card-columns .v-card {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
</style>
```

Comment: Try and make sure you use the correct tags for your question, also if you can provide code also.

Comment: I've provided the code as Answer. Please check once.

Answer (score 0):

Pardon me, I couldn't plunkr the code :(

This is what I did.

Update: Unfortunately this messes up with the v-ripple directive

```
<template>
<v-container grid-list-md>
    <div class="v-card-columns">
        <v-card tile v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
            <v-card-title primary-title>
                <h3 headline>
                    {{post.title}}
                </h3>
            </v-card-title>
            <v-card-text>
                {{post.body}}
            </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
    </div>
</v-container>
</template>
<script>

import axios from "axios";

export default {
    name: "All",
    data() {
        return {
            posts: []
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        axios
            .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
            .then(res => {
                this.posts = res.data
            })
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.v-card-columns .v-card {
    margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
    .v-card-columns {
        -webkit-column-count: 3;
        -moz-column-count: 3;
        column-count: 3;
        -webkit-column-gap: 1.25rem;
        -moz-column-gap: 1.25rem;
        column-gap: 1.25rem;
        orphans: 1;
        widows: 1;
    }

    .v-card-columns .v-card {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
</style>
```

Comment: You should put this into your question not as an answer.

Comment: Stackoverflow's self-answering steps were as in this way. It let me ask a question and then add an answer simultaneously.

Comment: You've misunderstood let me explain it to you, you originally posted a question with little to no detail asking for an answer providing no code, people downvoted presumably for that reason. You should update your question to include the code and or do an actual write up as to why this solved your problem. Because to me a likely others this entire question is pointless and not helpful to anyone in the future.